# i cant pass from array in the textfields numbers

Tags: java

Hi I have to do a lottery with numbers when I first choice in a panel when I press Start it should serve me a panel with figures given them passed to the constructor panel but while I normally displays the panel the numbers in the `JTextField` does not apper.

The code when I press the button to make a panel with numbers at the function that returns to 2nd table numbers I put here a system.out and she shows them normally underneath its constructor passing the table as a parameter.

```
if (source == start) {
   try {
     int numbers[][] = fucts.takeBulletin();
     RMIClient r=new RMIClient( numbers,1);
   }catch() {

   }
}
```

heare is the constructor code

```
public RMIClient(int  [][]numbs,int a)  {
    super("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!BINGO!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    Container pane = getContentPane();
    GridLayout layout=new GridLayout(7 , 7);
    pane.setLayout(layout);
    pane.add(numB);
    pane.add(numI);
    pane.add(numN);
    pane.add(numG);
    pane.add(numO); 
    pane.add(num13);
    for (int row = 0; row < numbs.length; row++) {    
        for (int col = 0; col < numbs[row].length; col++) {
            pane.add(new JTextField(""+numbs[row][col])); <----- is nedd " "+
        }
    }
    setContentPane(pane);
    pack();  

}
```

I can not understand why they do not pass the values ​​from the table in textfield , is show me empty textfields

Comment: What is the problem? Doesn't the code compile?

Comment: Does it compile?  Do you get errors?  Do you see anything that is causing this code to not work in the way you intend it?  Please provide a little more information.

Comment: if you actually want someone to help, kindly provide [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: No i not take error but i take an empty jetfields

Comment: I can not understand why they do not pass the values ​​from the table in textfield , is show me empty textfields

Comment: are you sure there are text fields?  maybe you got back an empty array [0][0], so there are no textfields at all?

Comment: Please give an example of specific input and the output that your program gives. Also describe how the output differs from what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a JApplet, try to move the whole content of the constructor into the init() method.

The constructor could save the int[][] numbs to an instance variable, and the init() method will see it.

```
int[][] numbs;

public RMIClient(int[][] numbs, int a)  {
  this.numbs = numbs;
}

public void init() {
...
}
```